# in code dom how to use in-built properties

Tags: c#, code-generation

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement hashTableParam = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement();
hashTableParam.Name = "hastable";
hashTableParam.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Collections.Hashtable));
```

Here i have created a `hashtable data type` using `code dom`.

Now i want to use its in-built properties such that `add`,`clear` etc to me. More clear i want to implement code similar to this one in code dom .

```
ht.add("key","value");
```

i tried to do like this

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement hashTableParam = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement();
hashTableParam.Name = "hastable";
hashTableParam.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Collections.Hashtable));

CodeMethodInvokeExpression invokeExp2 = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(new CodeVariableReferenceExpression(hashTableParam.Name), "add");
invokeExp2.Parameters.Add(new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression("key"));
invokeExp2.Parameters.Add(new CodeArgumentReferenceExpression("value"));
// CodeStatementCollection statements = new CodeStatementCollection();
return hashTableParam;
```

but i am not able to link between `invokeExp2` and `hashtableparam` .

Is there any other solution to use in built properties here i am trying use it has user defined

Answer (score 0):

The code you've got there looks like you're trying to pass the values of the **key** and **value** arguments passed to the method you're building add method of the hashtable:

```
void GeneratedMethod( string key, string value )
{
    ...
    hashtable.add( key, value );
}
```

If you're trying to pass the actual words "key" and "value" it looks more like this:

```
invokeExp2.Parameters.Add( new CodePrimitiveExpression( "key" ) );
invokeExp2.Parameters.Add( new CodePrimitiveExpression( "value" ) );
```

You've also got it set up to treat the hashTableParam variable itself as a method. Instead you'll want to use a [CodeMethodReferenceExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codemethodreferenceexpression.aspx).

```
invokeExp2 = 
new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeMethodReferenceExpression( 
        new CodeVariableReferenceExpression( hashTableParam.Name ),
        "add" )        
)
```

Comment: i did like that but i want it to be like ht.add("","");
the in built property of hash table data type